# Commutative finite group, $(A_1A_2\dots A_n)^2 = e$ and $A_1A_2\dots A_n=e$

Tags: group-theory

This is a question I am struggling to answer because my TA sent it to me for practice.

Say $G=\{A_1,A_2,A_3,\dots,A_n\}$ a commutative group so that $|G|=n$.

Prove that:

1. $(A_1A_2\dots A_n)^2 = e$.
2. If for every $A_i \in G$ which is different from $e$, $A_i^2 \ne e$, then
   $A_1A_2\dots A_n=e$.
3. If there is a single element $A_i \in G$ which is different from $e$ so that $A_i^2 = e$, then
   $A_i = A_1A_2\dots A_n$.

I really don't know how to approach this, and I still don't want a full answer.
I am asking for hints that will help me approach this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Hint: Remember that any element in $G$ has an unique inverse.

Comment: you mean Ai^(-1)?

Comment: Yes; it is also an element of the group, so $A_{i}^{-1}=A_j$ for a $1\leq j\leq n$.

Comment: Okay I have solved 1 and I think I know how to solve 2. Am I supposed to use the If statement?

Comment: You need to. Otherwise $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$ is a counterexample for $(ii)$.